# how to design api for a single page application having lot of dropdowns for which options has to be sent from backend

Tags: javascript, api, design-patterns, single-page-application, api-design

I am working on a Single page application with React, and I have lot of drop downs in the page. These drop downs contains multiple options, and I don't want to hard-code options in java script. Instead i need to get the options from API.

Is there any pattern used in such scenarios. I think of multiple ways

1. single API endpoint which returns all such metadata information like drop down options, menu options and even resource strings. This API will be called initial page load.
2. Individual APIs for every drop down or page. This API will be called when ever user navigates to new page in client.

Comment: I would prefer second one, data should be fetched when it is really needed, but if there are no so much data for drop downs - first way is also Okey

Comment: It can still be a single API endpoint, but instead of returning everything at once, you can pass a parameter and only return specific options.